# chrome extension - restriction on Chrome version

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use arrow functions in my chrome extension. Users with old Chrome versions (<45.0) will not be able to use it.

Is there a way to disable installation of my extension for users with old Chrome version?

Comment: See [minimum Chrome version](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/minimum_chrome_version) in manifest file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this string into your manifest file:

```
"minimum_chrome_version": "45"
```

All available options: [Manifest file format](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest).