# Installing the chrome extension only on the last or penultimate version of google chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to add `manifest.json` to the file so that the google chrome extension will be installed only on the last or penultimate version of the google chrome browser?

Comment: No. You'll have to write a utility that modifies `"minimum_chrome_version"` based on  Google's official API for current versions [like this one](https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/all), there could be others.

Comment: @wOxxOm I found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662118/chrome-extension-restriction-on-chrome-version; I have to put example: `"minimum_chrome_version": "45"`  in manifest.json. Do you think this is a good solution to limit to the last two versions?

Comment: I think my comment was self-explanatory. Is there something I should clarify?